# how to convert "dist" folder to its source "src" and other dependence folders and files

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

is there a way to convert or something like "dehash" "dist" folder in angular to its dependencies files?
I lost my source of project and don't have any idea how to get back my source :(

nothing I could yet . I tried nothing.plz help if there is a way

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any tools that provide such functionality. As you essentially want to reverse the compilation step, it would be pretty hard because many of the information present in source files get removed because they are only relevant for the compilation (i.e. config files, meta data, etc.).

Usually you would use git or a similar version control system and thus never loose anything.